# Global for all models with ignore options model wise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I am using `paper_trail (10.0.1)`. I have defined paper_trail to be available to all my models in `application_record` as

```
 has_paper_trail(
   on: %i[create, update],
   ignore: %i[created_at, updated_at],
   unless: proc { |obj| CONSTANT.include?(obj.class.name) }
)
```

I would like to define option for `ignore` common for few models and  specific for few other models.
For example say I have 10 models in which I have 5 models where `[created_at, updated_at]` would be ignored. And other 5 models have different attributes to be ignore.

Is there any possibilities to define DEFAULT_IGNORE options in  `application_record` and can we have constant specified model wise to call here in ignore to be used only for that model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Ruby, is there a way to 'override' a constant in a subclass so that inherited methods use the new constant instead of the old?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234384/in-ruby-is-there-a-way-to-override-a-constant-in-a-subclass-so-that-inherited)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possibilities to define DEFAULT_IGNORE options in application_record and can we [override that] constant [in the child classes]?

Yes, see: [In Ruby, is there a way to 'override' a constant in a subclass so that inherited methods use the new constant instead of the old?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234384/in-ruby-is-there-a-way-to-override-a-constant-in-a-subclass-so-that-inherited)

But, there are many other options here worth considering. Here's one design I like:

```
class ApplicationRecord
  def self.paper_trail_ignore
    %i[created_at updated_at]
  end
end

class Banana < ApplicationRecord
  def self.paper_trail_ignore
    %i[other_attribute]
  end
  has_paper_trail(ignore: paper_trail_ignore)
end
```

Edit: updated example to avoid calling `has_paper_trail` twice